# How to call HTTClient API call using iOS background session?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, httpclient, nsurlsession

I have a requirement to create a background Task to fetch API calls, using Xamarin.iOS. The API calls are fetched using `NSUrlSession CreateDownloadTask`, was able to fetch the API contents without any issues. But app's legacy API code was written using HTTPClient library & when calling `HTTPClient GetAsync` methods and moving the app to the background is causing this error

> NSURLErrorDomain - Lost connection to background transfer service.

Following is the code used to create HTTPClient background service

```
var configuration = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.CreateBackgroundSessionConfiguration(BackgroundSessionId);
                
                    configuration.HttpMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 6;
                    configuration.NetworkServiceType = NSUrlRequestNetworkServiceType.Background; 
                    configuration.AllowsCellularAccess = true;
                    configuration.WaitsForConnectivity = true;
                    configuration.AllowsConstrainedNetworkAccess = true;
                    configuration.AllowsExpensiveNetworkAccess = true;
                    configuration.ShouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode = true; 
                    configuration.TimeoutIntervalForRequest = 600.0;
                    configuration.TimeoutIntervalForResource = 1200.0;
    var handler = new NSUrlSessionHandler(configuration);
                var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(APIURL_DOWNLOAD);
                using (var content = response.Content)
                {
                    var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
```

I Would like to know a workaround to achieve HTTPClient calls in the background.

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe this could help you https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/9176